# How to add Header links to category section?

Tags: magento2, category, magento2.3, header

How to add Header links to category section?
i have some header links like new category , Brand , Contact Us. i have to show this header links in Main category section also.

[image]

[image]

Comment: can you please explain more.

Comment: i have some header links like new category , Brand , Contact Us. i have to show this header links in Main category section also.

Comment: simple just create category and assigned with static block in admin

Comment: you can use url rewrite

Answer (score 0):

solution is

Go to
Admin -> Marketing -> URL Rewrites (Under SEO & Search)